# Proof objects in the identity type

Tags: coq

I'm reading through software foundation and they define equality as

```
Inductive eq {X:Type} : X -> X -> Prop :=
  | eq_refl : forall x, eq x x.

Notation "x == y" := (eq x y)
                       (at level 70, no associativity)
                     : type_scope.
```

I've been able to prove `equality__leibniz_equality` using tactics

```
Lemma equality__leibniz_equality : forall (X : Type) (x y: X),
  x == y -> forall P:X->Prop, P x -> P y.
Proof.
  intros X x y H P evP. destruct H. apply evP.
Qed.
```

However I also wanted to construct the proof object. This is what I tried:

```
Definition equality__leibniz_equality' : forall (X : Type) (x y: X),
  x == y -> forall P:X->Prop, P x -> P y :=
  fun (X:Type) (x y: X) (H: x==y) (P:X->Prop) (evP: P x) =>
  match H with
  | eq_refl a => evP
  end.
```

While `destruct H` worked in my first proof, because the tactic immediately repaced `y` by `x`, however pattern matching `eq_refl a` does not seem to have a similar effect, so that it seems that the information that `x=y=a` is lost, and I get stucked. Is there a way to construct the proof object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Definition equality__leibniz_equality' : forall (X : Type) (x y: X),
  x == y -> forall P:X->Prop, P x -> P y :=
  fun (X:Type) (x y: X) (H: x==y) (P:X->Prop) =>
  match H with
  | eq_refl a => fun evP => evP
  end.
```

A better definition of `eq` which makes your definition pass is:

```
Inductive eq {X:Type} (x : X) : X -> Prop :=
  | eq_refl : eq x x.
```

You can use `Print` to look at the definition of any identifier. Or end the proof with `Defined` instead of `Qed` to compute with it or unfold it in another proof.

Answer (score 1):

It may also be interesting to look at the elimination principles generated by Coq, and play with `Check`.  With your definition:

```
Check eq_ind.
(*
eq_ind
     : forall (X : Type) (P : X -> X -> Prop),
       (forall x : X, P x x) -> forall y y0 : X, eq y y0 -> P y y0
*) 

Check fun (X: Type)(Q: X -> Prop) =>
        eq_ind _ (fun x y  => Q x -> Q y) (fun x Hx => Hx). 

fun (X : Type) (Q : X -> Prop) =>
eq_ind X (fun x y : X => Q x -> Q y) (fun (x : X) (Hx : Q x) => Hx)
     : forall (X : Type) (Q : X -> Prop) (y y0 : X), eq y y0 -> Q y -> Q y0
```

You may also compare this version of `eq` with Coq's `Logic.eq`(cf. Li-yao Xia's answer) by asking for the type of `Logic.eq_ind`.  Please note also there is no `eq_rec` nor `eq_rect` with your definition (in contrast to `Logic.eq`)

Answer (score 0):

```
Definition equality__leibniz_equality'' (X : Type) (x y: X) (H : x == y) (P : X -> Prop)
  : P x -> P y :=
    match H with
    | eq_refl x0 => id
    end.
                                            
Lemma equality__leibniz_equality''' : forall (X : Type) (x y: X),
    x == y -> forall P:X -> Prop, P x -> P y.
Proof.
  exact equality__leibniz_equality''.
Qed.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).